# Moving Locus at Twice the Distance From a Point

Tags: locus

I'm not sure where to start with this one. I can do differentiation fairly well, but this question has me stumped. I've come across a few locus questions before, but not sure about the general method and approach when dealing with one of these. Any hints?

Q: A point P(x,y) moves such that its distance from (1,2) is twice its distance from (-3,0). Find the cartesian equation of the locus of P, in its simplest form.

If anyone can help in any way, I appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: You don't need calculus for this. Just express the distance rule in terms of x and y, then simplify the resulting equation.

Comment: Let $A = (1,2)$, $B = (-3,0)$. 1) write down expressions for $|PA|$ and $|PB|$ in  $x,y$. 2) Try to solve $|PA| = 2|PB|$. 3) Too hard to solve because of absolute value. Try to solve $|PA|^2 - 4|PB|^2 = 0$ instead....